# tweaking image urls apache

Tags: php, image, apache, url-rewriting

I have a image hosting server, and i run multiple blogs were most of the images are shared and/or reused.

this is what i wanna achieve

`<img src="http//www.imagehost.com/demo1.jpg" />` - is the original place where the image is hosted

I want to tweak the "src" on "myblog" to look like = `<img src="http//www.myblog.com/demo1.jpg" />`

anything that can help me attain this.

Comment: "Tweak" how - on the blog's end, or on the server's end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways you could do this - none of which include apache. Apache can't spoof a root URL, which is what you are trying to do. You could create a file on your website (I'll use PHP for example) to fetch the remote file contents:

```
# get_file.php
$file = $_GET['file'];
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.imagehost.com/'.$file);
header('content-type: image/jpg');
echo $contents;
```

you'll need to enable remote file requests in your apache config for this method...
<img src="http://myblog.com/get_file.php?file=image.jpg" />

You could spoof preetier using .htaccess

```
# .htaccess
# after all other directives
RewriteRule /images/(.+)$ http://www.imagehost.com/$1 [L]
```

Then
<img src="http://myblog.com/images/image.jpg" />

In this case, you can never actually access myblog.com/images though...

Comment: Thanks a bunch Seth... will try these out

Comment: Hey Seth,

I tried the following:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/xyz/(.*)$ http://xyz.com/$1
</IfModule>


I uploaded the file to the root directory of the website and it seems to work fine, however the other links to the site have horribliy gone dead and dont come up any more :(.

Any hints to fix that too....

I am running wordpress blogs and this is for the same.

Also the images directory does not exist.

will upvote u, soon ;)

Comment: Hey Seth, sorry my bad, shud have followed exactly wht u prescribed, it works... and here comes the upvote